# How to Add Text Box On Top of Camera Layer in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, avfoundation, rsbarcodes

I'm building an app that implements barcode scanning functionality using RSBarcodes. I have the camera layer configured (standard view controller with custom class) and it's working properly. However, I want to have a text box that allows the user to input a barcode manually. When I add a textbox in the storyboard, it does not show up during a test. How do I get it to appear over the camera layer, if this is even possible?

[Here is the VC class.](https://github.com/yeahdongcn/RSBarcodes_Swift/blob/master/Source/RSCodeReaderViewController.swift)

Comment: show us the code what u have tried.

Comment: I haven't added any code for the textbox, just added it in the storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try outlet your control to the view controller and in `viewDidAppear:` bring it to front.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *your_control;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:your_control];
}
```